# SQL Server replication - error when creating a subscription - The article '(null)' does not exist

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, transactional-replication

When trying to add a subscription to an existing publication

```
use [Product]

exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'Product', 
        @subscriber = N'REPLON1', 
        @destination_db = N'Product', 
        @subscription_type = N'Pull', 
        @sync_type = N'none', 
        @article = N'all', 
        @update_mode = N'read only', 
        @subscriber_type = 0
```

This is some info that I found:

> sync_type is nvarchar(15),  with a default of  automatic. Can be
>   automatic or none.  If automatic, the schema and initial data for
>   published tables are transferred to the Subscriber first.  If none, it
>   is assumed the Subscriber already has the schema and initial data for
>   published tables.  System tables and data are always transferred.

This is the error I am getting:

> Msg 20027, Level 11, State 1, Procedure sp_MSadd_subscription, Line
>   228
>   The article '(null)' does not exist.
>
> Msg 14070, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_changesubstatus, Line 1213
>   Could not update the distribution database subscription table. The subscription status could not be changed.
>
> Msg 14057, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_MSrepl_addsubscription_article, Line 388
>   The subscription could not be created.

and when I run the script below, I get the exact same error.

```
exec sp_addsubscription @publication = N'Product', 
        @subscriber = N'REPLON1', 
        @destination_db = N'Product', 
        @subscription_type = N'Push', 
        @sync_type = N'automatic', 
        @article = N'all', 
        @update_mode = N'read only', 
        @subscriber_type = 0
```

Comment: `@sync_type = 'none'` has been deprecated.  Have you tried using `replication support only` for `@sync_type`?

Comment: also, of note: you could look at the procedures in question by right-clicking the name of the stored proc in object explore and clicking the "modify" menu item.   This might help you track down what is causing the `null` article error.